# Why is Next.js giving me an error of undefined when I am trying to pull data from firebase firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, array.prototype.map

This error makes no sense at all. This is the error I get when trying to get data from my firestore database.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

I think it is a firebase firestore related error but it is giving me that error which makes it hard for me to know what exactly is wrong because I know that is not the problem. This is where page where I have the code where I am extracting the data using getStaticProps

```
import img from "./img.png";
import Image from 'next/image';
import styles from "../styles/Card.module.css";
import { db } from "../firebase";
import { collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore'; 

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
    const reference = collection(db, "students");
    const data = await getDocs(reference);
    const theData = data.docs.map(doc => ({...doc.data(), id: doc.id}));
    console.log(data.name);

    return {
        props: {students: data}
    }
}
function Card({students}) {

  return (
    <div className={styles.cardContainer}>
        {students.map(student => (
            <div className={styles.card}>
                <div className={styles.first}>
                    <Image src={student.img} className={styles.imgr} width={200} height={150} alt="ima" placeholder='yeah bitch' />
                </div>
                <div className="second">
                    <h3>{student.name}</h3>
                    <p>{student.surname}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Card
```

This seems to me more like a firestore related problem not a looping problem. Where could I be going wrong?.

Comment: I would bet the error is correct. Which map is giving you the issue? The `students` or the `data.docs`? I'm guessing it's `data.docs`, and if so, why is your `data.docs` undefined? Have you looked at that variable, and if so provide more data? Because you say the error is not the problem... but `data.docs`, or whatever you are calling `map` on IS undefined.

Comment: @Diesel its the "students.map". it worked perfectly fine when I was using react useEffect without nextjs but now that i am using getStaticProps the error is saying the problem is with the map. I dont understand why

Comment: `data` is array or object? you are passing data as props and iterate it with map, but in your console, you are doing log `data.name` and mapping `data.doc`, actually you are going to pass `theData` as props and map it?, then error is clear?

Comment: are you using `getStaticProps` inside a page or a component? `getStaticProps` works only if used inside `/pages/`

Comment: @mocherfaoui its inside a component. I didnt know that let me try fix it

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment it runs just fine in `useEffect` but now it is failing. My guess is that it is failing on the server, and not on the client. `useEffect` does not ever run on the SSR. This is purely a hunch based on the data I have.

You could research how to check if you are on the server, and if so pass an empty array so `students` is not undefined. Or you could just always check for undefined and replace it with an empty array.

```
function Card({students}) {

  const definedStudents = students ?? []

  return (
    <div className={styles.cardContainer}>
        {definedStudents.map(student => (
            <div className={styles.card}>
                <div className={styles.first}>
                    <Image src={student.img} className={styles.imgr} width={200} height={150} alt="ima" placeholder='yeah bitch' />
                </div>
                <div className="second">
                    <h3>{student.name}</h3>
                    <p>{student.surname}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```